# MongoDB indexOnly false for covered query with sharding

Tags: mongodb

With MongoDB 2.6, when I execute  a covered query in a sharded database, indexOnly is false.  This is the case even in a simple test where I query only on a shard key value and request only the shard key in the results.  explain() shows indexOnly is false and nscannedObjects equals the number of objects found.   When I connect directly to the instance of mongod containing the specified shard key value and execute the same query,  indexOnly is true and nscannedObjects = 0, as I would expect.  Any explanation?

Comment: Please show the output or `db.yourCollection.getIndices()` your query and the output of explain.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same behavior - running locally without sharding, I'm seeing indexOnly=true and nscannedObject=0, but for the exact same query running through MongoS, I'm seeing a full table scan. This is on a field that is part of the shard key, too.

Comment: @patwhite: this is a known issue that has been fixed in the 2.7.x development cycle (see the duplicate issue for more info).